# Experiences with Nokia's Technical Support for Qt?

Tags: qt

Does anybody have experiences (good or bad) with Nokia's LGPL technical support (or even their commercial license support)? Is it worth the cost? How helpful are they/quality of responses? How responsive is Nokia?

http://shop.qt.nokia.com/us/support.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about end-user support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a commercial license and have contacted them about 10 different times and usually have a response within a day. Often times the e-mail indicates a workaround, alternative solution, or the correct way to handle what I was attempting.  When the issues have involved actual bugs, they've been prioritized and then become trackable on the public bug tracker. I've never needed to pursue a workaround for a bug that I've been aware of.

Comment: It's good to know that some companies still know how to provide good customer support. Nokia's support sounds top notch, I have yet to see a negative review. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with Kaleb. I also have a commercial license, and I have a similar experience. I am highly satisfied with their commercial support.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the cost (I'm not the one picking up the check), but from my experience the support is excellent. We've hit a Qt bug or two in the past, and they were quick to react with patches that solved the problem.